# How to configure the hostname shown in logs from a docker container?

Tags: docker, logging, systemd-journald

I log the activity of my docker containers via [`journald`](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/journald/). The hostnames provided by the containers are non-descriptive. An example for a Minecraft docker container:

```
Jul 25 16:51:38 srv c34ebd053ff5[19692]: [14:51:38 ERROR]: Could not pass event ArmorEquipEvent to Carmor v1.2.2
```

`c34ebd053ff5` is hardly informative, and I fear that it will change with time (with a new image for instance, if it is some kind of hash).

**Is there a way to force the name of a container for logging purposes?**

I tried to [use tags](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/log_tags/) `/etc/docker/daemon.json` but it did not help:

```
{
  "log-driver": "journald",
  "log-opts": {
    "tag": "{{.Name}}"
  }
}
```

EDIT: the containers are managed by `docker-compose` and each entry has a meaningful `container_name` (which therefore is not used in the logs by default)

Comment: `--hostname`, `--name` are both options for `docker run...`. Then just use either of those in your log-opts.

Comment: @johnharris85 I use `docker-compose` to handle my containers. Could your idea be ported to that? And when you say "use either" you mean for the `tag` entry? (`"tag": "hostname"`?)

Comment: You can use `container_name: XXX` in your `docker-compose.yml` then use use `{{.Name}}` as you have above in the `log-opts`.

Comment: @johnharris85 this is exactly what I have: a meaningful `container_name` and the `daemon.json` above → this does not change the logging information. I will update the question with that information

Comment: Works fine for me (https://gist.github.com/johnharris85/ad0f9ec1637c31586871237d82daf647). Can you double check, `/etc/docker/daemon.json` or `/etc/daemon.json`. The former is correct, but you've written the latter.

Comment: @johnharris85: you were right, there as a typo in the question with `daemon.json`, corrected. I found out that adding `hostname` was the way to fo, finally. Thanks for all the hints and follow-ups.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a `hostname` entry to `docker-compose.yml` :

```
  mc-mi:
    image: itzg/minecraft-server
    container_name: mc-mi
    hostname: mc-mi
```

From that point on, the logs were seen as coming from `mc-mi` instead of `c34ebd053ff5`.

It is worth noting that `container_name` is not used as `{{.Name}}`.

*Thank you to @johnharris85 for showing the way.*

Comment: Hmm .. and it didn't work for me